# Flow paragraph inside container slanted on both sides

Tags: css

What I want to do:
Fill multi-line text within a skewed container, making it a parallelogram shape. I also want to make the content be able to scroll up and down.

[image]

All I could manage was:

[image]

I also want to use media queries to show it without slant on mobile devices.

This is the approach I took, with the full code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/japanyoshi/pen/LYGEPzx?editors=1100).

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  #scroller {
    transform: skew(-30deg);
  }

  #content > .unskew {
    transform: skew(30deg);
  }

  .contentMargin {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45vh;
  }

  p {
    transform: skew(30deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try shape outside for this:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify;
}

.container>div {
  height: 100%;
}

.container::before,
.container>div::before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff 49%, transparent 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000 40%, #fff 40.5% 49.5%, transparent 50%)
}

.container>div::before {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: linear-gradient(to top left, #fff 49%, transparent 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #000 40%, #fff 40.5% 49.5%, transparent 50%)
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {
  .container::before,
  .container>div::before {
    content: none;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Title </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec elit nisi. Sed a mi vel mi auctor vehicula id molestie turpis. Praesent et sem mattis, efficitur nisi at, mattis sapien. Mauris sit amet lacus ante. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas massa
      orci, cursus sed maximus maximus, sollicitudin sed justo</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec elit nisi. Sed a mi vel mi auctor vehicula id molestie turpis. Praesent et sem mattis, efficitur nisi at, mattis sapien. Mauris sit amet lacus ante. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas massa
      orci, cursus sed maximus maximus, sollicitudin sed justo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks close, but the frame moves with the content, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [CSS Shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes/Overview_of_CSS_Shapes). Use polygon() to make the shape as complex as you want.
Here is small example of what you need.

```css
.shape {
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  shape-outside: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 10% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="shape"></div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only cuts the shape out on one side. Scrolling doesn't play nice with it either.